# Writing $(a)_k*(a)_k$ as one Pochhammer Symbol or in terms of one Gamma ($\Gamma$) function?

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, pochhammer-symbol

I have two identical Pochhammer symbol multiplication as $(a)_k*(a)_k$. I would like to express this multiplication as only one Pochhammer symbol or only one Gamma function. Could anyone have any idea to solve my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean such as $((a)_k(a)_k)_1$?

Comment: I mean such as  $(a)_k*(a)_k$ = $(b)_n$ or  $(a)_k*(a)_k$ = $\Gamma(...)$